# Showing $\int_0^\infty x^je^{-\beta x} dx=\frac{j!}{\beta^{j+1}}$ for $j\in\Bbb Z,\beta>0.$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Show that $$\int_0^\infty x^je^{-\beta x} dx=\frac{j!}{\beta^{j+1}}$$ for $j\in\Bbb Z,\beta>0.$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've got an unnecessary differentiation proof here if you like.

$\int_0^{\infty} x^j e^{-\beta x}dx = \frac{d^j}{d\beta^j}[(-1)^j\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\beta x}dx]$

Comment: I tried the substitution u= and then integrated by parts, w=u^r and dv=e^(-u), by repeating the process and evaluating in 0 and infinity the result is indeed !/^(+1)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To avoid having your questions closed, avoid asking problem statement questions. You can do this by including more information, such as where you got this problem and what you have tried, even if you don't think it will lead anywhere. If you do have such information, [edit] your question to reflect this. Such information helps us help you, so you will be expected to bring something to the table when posting questions. For more information, see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the following substitution: $u=\beta x$ and induction on $j$ after that. (And note that it's only valid for $j \geqslant 0$.)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty x^je^{-\beta x} \, dx \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {\beta^{j+1}} \int_0^\infty (\beta x)^j e^{-\beta x} ( \beta\, dx) \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {\beta^{j+1}} \int_0^\infty u^j e^{-u} \, du = \frac{j!}{\beta^{j+1}}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For the induction step,
since
$(f(x)e^{-x})'
=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))
$,
$\int f(x) e^{-x}dx
=\int f'(x)e^{-x} dx - f(x)e^{-x}
$.

(IBP, really)

If $f(x) = x^n$,
this is
$\int x^n e^{-x}dx
=\int nx^{n-1}e^{-x} dx - x^ne^{-x}
$.

Let
$I_n(t)
=\int_0^t x^n e^{-x}dx
$,
with
$I_0(t)
=\int_0^t e^{-x}dx
=1-e^{-t}
$.

Then
$I_n(t)
=nI_{n-1}(t)-t^ne^{-t}
$
so that
$I_n(\infty)
=nI_{n-1}(\infty)
$
which leads directly to
$I_n(\infty)
=n!
$.

A little extra.

If we write
$J_n(t)
=e^tI_n(t)
$,
then
$J_0(t)
=e^t-1
$
and
$J_n(t)
=nJ_{n-1}(t) - t^n
$.

That $n$ leads me to divide by $n!$
and we get
$\dfrac{J_n(t)}{n!}
=\dfrac{J_{n-1}(t)}{(n-1)!} - \dfrac{t^n}{n!}
$.
or
$\dfrac{J_n(t)}{n!}-\dfrac{J_{n-1}(t)}{(n-1)!} 
=- \dfrac{t^n}{n!}
$.

Summing,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^m - \dfrac{t^n}{n!}
&=\sum_{n=1}^m(\dfrac{J_n(t)}{n!}-\dfrac{J_{n-1}(t)}{(n-1)!} )\\
&=\dfrac{J_m(t)}{m!}-\dfrac{J_0(t)}{0!}\\
&=\dfrac{J_m(t)}{m!}-J_0(t)\\
&=\dfrac{J_m(t)}{m!}-(e^t-1)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$J_m(t)
=m!(e^{t}-1-\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac{t^n}{n!})
=m!(e^{t}-\sum_{n=0}^m \dfrac{t^n}{n!})
$
and
$I_m(t)
=e^{-t}m!(e^{t}-\sum_{n=0}^m \dfrac{t^n}{n!})
=m!(1-e^{-t}\sum_{n=0}^m \dfrac{t^n}{n!})
$.

Then,
as expected,
$I_m(\infty)
=m!
$.